# Visual Studio Code SVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio-code, tortoisesvn

how can I use SVN on Visual Studio Code? 
I installed TortoiseSvn but I didn't find how can I use.
I want to use commit, update, replace, show history..
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can install this tool:
[TortoiseSVN for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cdsama.tortoise-svn-for-vscode)

EDIT: This extension is no longer supported or available on VS Code Marketplace.

You may use [TortoiseSVN](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fantasytyx.tortoise-svn) or [SVN](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnstoncode.svn-scm) instead

Comment: Can you actually browse repositories? The documentation there seems a bit sparse.